# Prevent download of MP3 files in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, file, .htaccess, mp3, audio-streaming

I know many people asks the opposite of what I am asking. I am trying to make browsers play the file instead of downloading when opening the mp3 files´ link. I do not care if the users download the file after that, but I need the browsers to play the file at first, instead of automatically downloading. It happens in computers and smarthphones.
, b
I don´t know if it is something I have to change in .htaccess file or somewhere else. The link to the site is this: https://cefadchurch.com/sermones/predicas-dominicales/
Try the download button. If you see, it directly sends you to the file´s link, but it starts downloading instead playing. I know a "Download" button function is obviously to make the browser download the file, but that will not be the case for me, because however, if the button sends me to the file´s link, I rather the browser play instead download, and the company has asked me for that function.

Answer (score 1):

In your response headers, you're actively forcing the download in two ways:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Firstly, the `Content-Disposition` header value of `attachment` [forces a download to occur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition).  You must get rid of it if you want to not have a forced download.

Next, the content type of `application/octet-stream` is the generic binary type, and thus the browser doesn't know how to render it so just downloads it as a file to let the system handle it.  If you're sending MP3s, use `audio/mpeg` for the `Content-Type` response header.

Finally, not all browsers can/will play media in a tab when you link to the media directly.  If you want the file to play in-browser, you need to embed it into a web page with the `<audio>` tag.